# When using a tethered device to debug, which Google Maps API key do I use?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, api-key

I know there are a number of questions about using a Google Maps API key, but none of them have been answered since V1 went extinct.  I am having trouble loading in the map tiles on my MapView.  I am using an API key derived from the debug keystore and I am debugging using a Nexus 7 tethered via USB.  Somewhere I believe I read that if you are using USB debugging, the debug key will not work - is this true? How do I work around this if I cannot get a virtual device to run on my machine? The MapView shows up fine, but I am getting the "Server returns 3" error, which I understand has to do with the key not matching.  Here's the view in my layout file, as well as my manfiest:

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
  android:id="@+id/map"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="100dp"
  android:clickable="true"
  android:apiKey="AIzaSyDXlQso2Xzo4vhLt3gqZAFuoYt081cao8M"
  android:visibility="visible"
/>
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.casson.sherpy"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="11"
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<permission
    android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.example.mapdemo.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission   android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"     android:permission="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">
    <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />

    <activity
        android:name="com.casson.sherpy.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="AIzaSyDXlQso2Xzo4vhLt3gqZAFuoYt081cao8M"/>

</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no problem with using the debug key with debugging on.  It may be due to your lack of a uses-library statement in your manifest.  But I'd really suggest moving on from V1 to the current version-  keys are much easier to deal with there (you just need to put the key and appname into a website, not in the xml at all).

Comment: Thanks for the answer - sorry if I was unclear, I actually am using V2 here.  And do I need another uses-library? I already have <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" /> in there.  I'm glad you pointed me in this direction, though, I noticed that I had forgotten to replace the example package name with my own for the MAPS_RECEIVE permission

Comment: If you are on v2, then you don't need the key in the xml layout-  it goes once in a meta-data tag in the manifest.